# Inserting nodes from DataGridView into a TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I don't know how to manage that correctly so I have to ask here.
I have this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cusIds.Count; i++)
        {

            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(cusIds[i]);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
```

cusIds is a List where all customer IDs are stored once (DISTINCT - taken from a datagridview). Now I have a datatable called dtFoundIds which stores every single row from a datagridview where the IDs which appear in my List above are prresent (in the datagridview a customer ID cann appear multiple times).
The code above creates the nodes for the tree which are the customer IDs. Now I wanted to add type numbers to each ID which are listed in the datagridview. The records in the datagridview look like:

```
  CUSid |TypeNum
  ------------------
  111   | 234
  111   | 211
  122   | 123
  122   | 556
  122   | 222
```

So how can I fill the type numbers as child nodes into the Ids? I want to have one node for every ID and then the type numbers as childnodes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `node.ImageKey` or `node.Name` and pass the value on it

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
node.ImageKey = Convert.ToString(cusIds.Rows[i]["CUSid"]);
node.Name = Convert.ToString(cusIds.Rows[i]["TypeNum"]);
```

Comment: How would that look like in code? Let's say we would use the example datagridview rows I posted above. I would have to search them in the datagridview, right?

Comment: This assigns only names and imagekeys to my tree? I need to fill the already existing parent nodes (CUSId) with the childnodes (TypeNum)

Comment: Have you tried to use IF statement? And check if the ID of your grid and treeview are the same then assign the TypeNum

Comment: I'm trying right now but I can't find the correct syntax. I tried for example if(rootNode.Name == dtFoundIds[j].Value). How do I loop through the row with the column name XXX in my datatable?

Comment: `if (rootNode.Name == Convert.ToString(dtFoundIds[j]["COLUMNNAME"]))`

Comment: Ok he tells me that I can't use the brackets [ ] when I make a for loop (for int j = 0; j < dtFoundIds.Rows.Count; j++). When I try to use a foreach loop (foreach(DataTable row in dtFoundIds.Rows)) I try to put  'rows' instead of 'j' and he also can't find it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76003/discussion-between-jayvee-and-scorpx).